# Loop error while converting Text to Number across all sheets with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'd like your help to repeat the below code to all file sheets to convert "Column B" from text to number. I have tried next for function but it gives me error every time I run it.

[Screen shot from the file sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diskV.jpg)

---

```
    Sub convert ()
    
    [B:B].Select
        With Selection
            .NumberFormat = "General"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End Sub
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Use "Option Explict"

Comment: Avoid "Select"!

Comment: `Sub convert2(): Dim ws As Worksheet: For Each ws In Worksheets: With Range("B1").CurrentRegion: .NumberFormat = "General": .Value = .Value: End With: Next ws: End Sub`

Comment: Dear,
I have try your suggestion but it run only in current sheet but not following sheets

Sub convert2():
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets

With Range("B1").CurrentRegion
.NumberFormat = "General"
.Value = .Value
End With

Next ws

End Sub

Comment: `Sub convert2() : Dim ws As Worksheet : For Each ws In Worksheets : debug.print ws.name : With Range("B1").CurrentRegion : .NumberFormat = "General" : .Value = .Value : End With : Next ws : End Sub` ??? This loops over all worksheets! debug.print added: lists all worksheet names in the immediate window! (CTRL G!)